# How to conditionally fill a dataframe with another one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, find, fill

I have two dataframes with different dimensions, and I want to fill a column based on same values in the other dataframe, here is an example :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76kbE.jpg)

DATA1 dimensions are bigger than DATA2 dimensions

I tried to run it with for loops but it's too slow :

```html
for i in range(0,len(DATA1.index):
    for j in range(0,DATA2.index):
        if DATA1['val1'][i] == DATA2['val3'][j]:
            DATA1['val2'][i] = DATA2['val4'][j]:
```

Is there any another way to run it faster with pandas dataframes ?

Answer (score 0):

Did not tried this but it should help

```
dictionary = dict(zip(DATA2["val3"], DATA2["val4"]))
DATA1["val2"] = DATA1["val1"].map(dictionary)
```

if not try this

```
dictionary = dict(zip(DATA2["val3"], DATA2["val4"]))
DATA1["new_val"] = DATA1["val1"].map(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming val3 to val1 and merge the dataframes based on column name val1

```
data2.rename(columns={'val3': 'val1'}
data=pd.merge(data1,data2,on=['val1'],how='left')
del data['val2'] #since that column will still have the 0's
```